# Jackiw-Teitelboim (JT) gravity as a matrix integral

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, holographic-principle, matrix-model

I am reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11115 by Saad, Shenker and Stanford. They relate an (averaged) $n$-point function in a random double-scaled matrix model to a path integral genus expansion in JT gravity.
Since they use Eynard-Orantin recursion relation for matrix models (https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3600), which is true for polynomial matrix actions, I guess the matrix model is in zero spacetime dimensions.

The question is thus the following: in what sense is this an example of holography, if the matrix model is in zero dimensions and JT gravity is in 2d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On one hand, the [holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle) refers in Ref. 1 to the nearly asymptotic Euclidean $AdS_2$ (given by [Jackiw-Teitelboim (JT) gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackiw%E2%80%93Teitelboim_gravity) with disc topology $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$) and the nearly $CFT_1$ on its boundary $\partial D\cong \mathbb{S}^1$ (with a [Schwarzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) action).
2. On the other hand, 2D gravity are related to random matrix models in 0+0D via a genus expansion of [Riemann surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface), i.e. a 1D complex manifold, i.e. a 2D real manifold, cf. Ref. 2. The matrix elements $M^i{}_j\in \mathbb{C}$ are associated with [double-line](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%27t+Hooft+double+line+notation) triangularizations of Riemann surfaces. So in that sense the 2D are more related to the target space than the 0+0D world-volume of the matrix model, cf. OP's question.

References:

1. Ph. Saad, S.H. Shenker & D. Stanford, *JT gravity as a matrix integral,* [arXiv:1903.11115](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11115).
2. P. Di Francesco, P. Ginsparg & J. Zinn-Justin, *2D Gravity and Random Matrices*, [arXiv:hep-th/9306153](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306153).

Comment: I think there's an important point I was missing while asking this question. Although the matrix model doesn't have any derivative term in the action (thus it's non-dynamical), it is not technically true that the matrix theory lives in a zero-dimensional spacetime. The matrix in the path integral does depend on a parameter, call it $t$. So we could say that the matrix model does not live in a space (or lives on a point), but does evolve in time. Some people speculate that a holographic interpretation could be the following: when going to the two-dimensional theory, this $t$ becomes the time...

Comment: (let me continue here)
...in the gravity theory, while the matrix itself becomes the other coordinate, i.e. the spatial one.